# Versátil tradução para Português de "offset", "inset", "outset"

Tags: português-europeu, tradução-inglês, estrangeirismos

Tenho estado recentemente a trabalhar nalgumas traduções de interfaces de utilizador de programas de computador.
Um das muitas ocorrências que me tem eludido frequentemente é uma boa tradução para o conceito de *offset*, e as palavras vizinhas complementares "*inset*" e *outset*.

Para contextualizar estamos a falar de softwares de edição gráfica e modelação 3D. Geralmente o termo *offset* refere-se a variados tipos de operações que criam formas geométricas paralelas a partir de um original, dado um determinado afastamento. *Inset* seria então criar uma forma paralela à original menor que esta, para o interior da mesma, enquanto o *outset* seria o equivalente para o seu exterior.

Imagens valem por mil palavras, eis alguns exemplos no software de ilustração gráfica vectorial Inkscape.

[image: Offset no Inkscape]

A operação equivalente no software de modelação 3D Blender.

[image: Inset no Blender 3D]

Para clarificar, falaríamos de *inset* no caso a amarelo [image: Circunferência Amarela], em que a forma paralela fica para o interior da original (a azul e branco [image: Circunferência Azul Branca]), e *outset* a rosa [image: Circunferência Rosa], em que a forma paralelo fica para o exterior da original.

[image]

Procurava uma palavra que pudesse funcionar bem simultaneamente como substantivo e como verbo, e cujo verbo isolado (*offset*) parecesse minimamente elucidativo quando aparecesse isolado (numa listagem num menu por exemplo); mas nenhuma até agora nenhuma preencheu satisfatoriamente todos os requisitos. Já ponderei várias hipóteses, mas cada uma tem os seus senões.

| Offset | Inset | Outset | Comentátio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dilatação/Compressão | Contrair | Dilatar | Verbos funcionam bem, nenhum dos substantivos exprime bem as duas ideias. Houve quem mencionasse aludir a termos de partos |
| Deslocamento | Comprimir | Expandir | Substantivo isolado parece vago. Verbos funcionam bem, mas poderão ser vagos |
| Afastamento | Afastar para dentro | Afastar para fora | Substantivo funciona bem, mas fora de contexto pode não ser claro. Verbos prolixos |
| Rebordo | Fazer rebordo interior | Fazer rebordo exterior | Substantivo funciona bem, não tem bom verbo equivalente ("rebordar"?) |
| Moldura | Emoldurar para dentro | Emoldurar para fora | Pouco claro, não tem bom verbo equivalente, prolixo |
| Margem | Criar margem interna | Criar margem externa | Podem confundir com margem das páginas, prolixo |
| Paralelo | Paralelizar para interior | Paralelizar para exterior | Não tem bom verbo equivalente, prolixo |

Esgotei o meu vocabulário e não me ocorre mais nenhum sinónimo adequado para aparecer numa interface gráfica e que seja acessível a um utilizador comum. Alguém tem uma sugestão melhor? Existem no vocabulário português expressões mais adequadas para operações do género? Talvez na gíria da marcenaria ou carpintaria, mas o meu *search-fu* tem-me falhado.

Não havendo alternativas melhores, um compromisso aceitável seria uma opção combinada, por exemplo **Rebordo**, **Comprimir**, **Expandir**

Alternativamente, seria aceitável estrangeirismos neste contexto? Para mim parecem me termos familiares, mas já estou habituado a lidar com estas operações. Para um público alvo de uma tradução para Português da interface (que pode ou não saber Inglês) poderá não ser compreensível. O que acham?

Comment: Outras hipóteses que me ocorreram entretanto, mas que me parecem mais "exóticas": acolchoar, enchumaçar, almofadar.

Comment: Não se traduz! Esses neologismos são nomes compostos que formam uma semantica própria quase separada dos radicais que compõem o composto. Ao contrário dos franceses, que decidiram traduzir a totalidade do vocabulário informático os portugueses adoptam em geral a terminologia estrangeira para evitar a redundância e confusão de duplicar os termos. Isso implica que frequentmente não se vão traduzir os termos fora de alguns ramos das ciências exactas (como o física e a medicina por exemplo). (Falta aqui uma referência para suportar isto mas é o que se diz correntemente no ensino.)

Comment: O sítio mais provável para encontrar uma solução para estas traduções é na literatura especializada das artes gráficas e da arquitectura. Embora, parece-me possivel pelos exemplos que incluiste para essas 3 palavras que sejam hiperônimos de sentidos - como encontras 7 traduções possiveis para cada um dos termos. Portanto pode ser um caso de ontologia técnica em que o termo geral que denomine os 3 conceitos seja uma convenção à qual não se chega por uso intuitivo da lingua.

Comment: Repara também cuidadosamente na semântica dos compostos do inglês (partindo da morfologia derivacional): "off+set" seria "fora+conjunto"... Portanto o composto acarreta pouca ou nenhuma semântica dos constituintes (são os casos da *"morfo-semântica"* cujo exemplo paradigmático é o [Cranberry morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme). As traduções que fazes vão quase todas para radicais simples de etimologia latina, portanto com sentidos bem cristalizados e definidos. O que te leva a corresponder vários termos individuais de semânticas circunscritas ao hiperônimo do inglês.

Comment: Não sei se *offset* será necessariamente um neologismo, provavelmente tem raízes anteriores nas artes manuais, desenho, ou anterior até, mas confesso que não investiguei. Concordo plenamente contigo em adoptar os estrangeirismos por contraponto aos Franceses; não usasse eu todos esses softwares em Inglês por não simpatizar com traduções. A minha questão é que se os restantes utilizadores pensarem como nós, os únicos que vão que usar as traduções são mesmo quem não sabe ponta de Inglês. Para mim não me incomodaria de todo, mas para eles os estrangeirismos provavelmente não serão úteis.

Comment: Lembro-me de há muito tempo ter lido uma explicação sobre a etimologia de *"offset"* em que o constituinte *"set"* referia o conjunto de caractéres da [prensa movel](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prensa_m%C3%B3vel) e o constituinte *"off"* era sobre a peça que fazia uma linha deslocar-se e manter-se fixa num sítio (portanto *"fora da linha"* e olhando para a mecânica original da coisa o uso do termo fazia pleno sentido). Se investigares por ai provavelmente vais encontrar não só a lógica original do termo como também a tradução geralmente adoptada (já passarem 500 anos desde Gutenberg).

Comment: Entretanto o Wiktionary tem a seguinte etimologia: 
From off- +‎ set, used to construct the noun form of the verb to set off. Compare Middle English ofsetten (“to encumber, harass, beset, besiege”), from Old English ofsettan (“to press, oppress, overwhelm, crush”).

Comment: A etimologia e formação de palavras da wikipedia não é de confiar. Eu estava a ler a [versão 3.0 do UniMorph](https://rycolab.io/publication/mccarthyal-lrec-20/) em que era dito que parte significativa do trabalho deles era rever erros do wiktionary pois a formação de palavras lá constante frequentemente contém erros porque foi gerada informaticamente por algoritmo sem revisão humana.

Comment: Outras opções que me ocorreram entretanto **Guarnecer** Guarnição Interior, Guarnição Exterior. **Orlar**, Orla Interior Orla Exterior

Comment: offset não é nenhum neologismo. Em finanças, quer dizer compensação, outro sentido de termo.

Comment: Faz anos e anos que meixo com esses termos. Acho que precisas entender o que quer dizer offset [from a line]: colocar algo a uma distancia x de uma linha/limite y. inset colocar algo dentro de outro elemento ou forma (que tenha uma forma qualquer.) com um limite y. outset: colocar algo fora de ou ao exterior de um elemento. Porque *set* aqui quer dizer colocar ou posicionar. No caso, todas as formas são geométricas. Le a minha explicação, te ajudará.

Comment: @bad_coder Isso é offset printing: outra ideia.  https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/offset-printing-offset-lithography#:~:text=Offset%20printing%2C%20also%20called%20offset,contact%20with%20the%20metal%20plates. Offset printing, also called offset lithography, is a method of mass-production printing in which the images on metal plates are transferred (offset) to rubber blankets or rollers and then to the print media.

Comment: É uma pena Duarte que você não se interessa às minhas explicações *do inglês*, por ser  nativa falante. Não digo a melhor tradução; digo uma boa explicação do inglês. Tenho 35 anos de experiência como tradutora na outra direção (para o ingles) e conheço muito bem o problema de offset. Nem sei porque tento compartilhar o que sei.

Comment: @Lambie agradeço as explicações e o investimento que dedicaste a responder à minha questão, não foram ignorados. Não sou tradutor, mas também conheço bem os termos antes até de os utilizar no Inkscape ou Blender. Vou discutir as respostas que obtive com a minha colega de tradução para chegarmos a uma conclusão satisfatória. A minha preocupação não é tanto exclusivamente com a exactidão técnica da tradução em si, mas sim em encontrar um termo que seja fácil entender para leigos.

Comment: Tu se calhar sabes melhor que ninguém que a maioria dos utilizadores acaba por se habituar a utilizar estes software em Inglês sem traduções. Com isso em mente provavelmente quem vai utilizar os interfaces em Português será mesmo só quem não percebe nada de Inglês. Por essa razão estava à procura de termos que acima de tudo fossem relativamente fáceis para um leigo, ainda que não sejam uma tradução precisa do Inglês para *offset* ou *inset*

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Vou mudar a minha resposta amanhã. Não tenho tempo agora. Para levar em conta a duas coisas (Inkscape e Blender). No fundo, acaba sendo o mesmo mas não parece na supercie. Infelizmente, não há termo fácil nessa jogada :)

Comment: Sim, sem pressa, obrigado. Em todos os softwares que utilizei penso que não existe grandes diferenças entre eles nas diversas operações de *offset*. Umas bidimensionais, outras tridimensionais, mas o princípio fundamental é sempre o mesmo: criar formas paralelas a uma forma base dada uma determinada distância

Answer (score 2):

Sugestão (nova): **deslocar** (**pontos**), **comprimir**, **expandir**.

Num primeiro momento sugeri "redimensionar", mas esse termo corresponde melhor ao "*scale*". Também me opus inicialmente a "deslocar", mas aqui se trata efetivamente de um jargão que, como tal, não precisa respeitar a conotação cotidiana.

No contexto (programas de manipulação gráfica), entendendo que o que está sendo deslocado são os pontos que definem os assim chamados "caminhos" (*paths*), o que pode levar à mudança de forma, dependendo das propriedades das linhas que ligam esses pontos. Então de fato há um deslocamento, embora não da imagem como um todo. Eu ainda evitaria "afastar", que não me parece se aplicar bem à compressão, em que os pontos na verdade se aproximam.

---

[original]:

Pela imagem de exemplo que você dá, "to offset" não tem o sentido usual de deslocamento que Lambie referencia, nem exatamente o de "to scale (an object)", já que não apenas o tamanho do objeto, mas também (pelo menos no caso da expansão no exemplo) sua forma se alteram com a operação. Não me ocorre nenhuma palavra que tenha exatamente esse sentido, mas "redimensionamento" poderia ser uma aproximação aceitável. [edit] Como colocado acima, essa palavra é na verdade uma tradução para "scaling".

Quanto às demais opções, pessoalmente, "*rebordo*" não é nada claro para mim. E, após checar dicionários ([1](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/rebordo), [2](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/rebordo/), [3](https://www.aulete.com.br/rebordo)), parece não se aplicar bem à operação de comprimir. O mesmo se pode dizer de "moldura". "*Paralelo*", "*deslocamento*" e "*afastamento*" todos invocam a translação do objeto, não na alteração de seu tamanho ou forma. "*Margem*" poderia uma extensão semântica interessante, mas sem dúvida com potencial para confundir mais que esclarecer.

Answer (score 0):

Possível opção que me ocorreu entretanto Contornar.

Segundo o Priberam pode ser utilizado para se referir a fazer um contorno (ênfase meu)

> ### contornar
>
> verbo transitivo
>
> 1. **Marcar o contorno de.**
> 2. Dar volta a.
> 3. Passar pela parte exterior de.
> 4. Arredondar (frases, períodos).
> 5. [Figurado] Querer penetrar as intenções de alguém.
> 6. [Heráldica] Contrabandar.
> 7. [Heráldica] Voltar para a parte esquerda do escudo.
>
> "contornar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/contornar.

Contorno, Contornar por fora, Contornar por dentro.

Desvantagens

- Na forma de verbo poderá ser erradamente interpretado como "evitar algo" ou "contornar a rotunda"
- Não sei se funciona para o caso de *inset*, não se é inteiramente correcto dizer-se "contorno interior" ou se contorno pressupõe que é forçosamente exterior

Comment: contornar não tem nada que ver. Não é contornar. offset é posicionar ou colocar um elemento a x distância de algo, normalmente uma linha. Se usa muito em formatação e desenho. Se fala em offset distance. Ou seja, a distância de deslocamento...

Comment: Penso que as desvantagens que você lista, Duarte, pesam muito contra essa opção.

Comment: Concordo, penso que não satisfazem totalmente

Comment: Blender e Inkscape usam o termo de maneira um pouco diferente um do outro, Você não foi claro nisso.

Comment: Duarte? Você viu o que mudei na resposta? Por favor, responde a nova informação segundo os dois programas.

Comment: Vi sim, Lambie obrigado. Agradeci no comentário à pergunta mas em referência à tua actualização. Provavelmente só terei oportunidade de conferenciar com a minha colega de tradução para o próximo fim de semana, mas nessa altura discutiremos a melhor opção. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Isto vem de **Inkscape. Tudo claramente definido:**

> Inset and outset
> **Inkscape can expand and contract shapes not only by scaling, but also by offsetting an object's path, i.e. by displacing it
> perpendicular to the path in each point.** The corresponding commands
> are called Inset (+) and Outset (+). Shown below is the original path
> (red) and a number of paths inset or outset from that original: [se ve
> no original na página, que o outset e inset producem camihos
> interiores ou exteriores ao caminho original.
>
> Tradução [...] pelo **deslocamento do objeto** em (linha)
> perpendicular ao caminho em cada ponto. Os commandos correspondentes
> se chamam **inserção interior** (Inset) ou **inserção exterior** (ao
> caminho original do objeto)].
>
> [offset, inset and outset from Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.html#:%7E:text=Paths%20are%20edited%20by%20drag,to%20restrict%20movement%20and%20rotation.)

Da Priberam: declocar 2. **Fazer mudar de lugar. = MOVER, TRANSFERIR**

"deslocar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024,[deslocar](https://%20https://dicionario.priberam.org/deslocar.)

2. Aqui temos outro texto do programa Blender. No Blender estão trabalhando com **figuras geométricas** e deslocamento na face de uma superfície, por exemplo, de um quadrado sólido [ou com quatro faces]:

Eles explicam o inset e outset assim:

> **This tool takes the currently selected faces and creates an inset of them**, with adjustable thickness and depth.** *Think of it as like
> creating an edge loop, but relative to the selected edges, even in
> complex meshes*.
>
> Tradução: Essa ferrmento pega as faces selecionadas e cria um traço
> contínuo ou inserção deles, cuja espessura e profundidade podem se
> ajustar.
>
> Se ve isso e o processo em um desenho deles aqui: [inset on face of
> square](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html)

[Blender_outro vídeo do processo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iUPTNoq9zU)

3. Uma notinha: em inglés, offset é uma distância de um objeto de um reto dado.
   Por exemplo: offset **from the margin**. Isso corresponde ao que diz a texto acime do Inkscape.

Outro exemplo de offset:

> As notas de rodapé devem ser inseridas com fonte Times New Roman,
> corpo 10, espaço 1,0 (simples), cor preto, justificado, deslocamento
> [offset] 0,5 cm.
>
> [Normas ABNT](https://tecnologiaemeventos.furg.br/images/Normas_ABNT_para_TCC_.pdf)

deslocamento = offset

> 2. Projeto iniciado ou não: o modelo 3D está deslocado [vertically offset] na vertical em relação aos pavimentos da edificação
>
> [deslocamento](https://suporte.altoqi.com.br/hc/pt-br/articles/360010795293-Modelo-3D-IFC-importado-fica-deslocado-no-AltoQi-Builder)

[Já cansei de procurar. Só queria dar aqui o offset usado em arquitetura e em arte gráfica/formatação.

Uma definição de inset quer dizer inserção [numa imagem, e não só de uma imagem]. inserção interna [como disse acima, em relação a um reto]

Outset: inserção externa

Comment: "Inserção" para *inset* é de facto uma das sugestões que já tenho encontrado, mas que me deixou na dúvida, especialmente para Português Europeu se seria correcta. "Deslocamento", ou até "afastamento" são as que tenho usado até agora para *offset*, por isso confirmam os nossos palpites

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Português europeu ou brasileiro, que diferença faz aqui? Nenhuma na minha opinião. Offset não é afastamento.

Comment: Considerando que estamos a fazer uma tradução para Português Europeu, diria que faz toda a diferença

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos  Inserção e formatação de conteúdo multimédia https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o Esse tipo de terminologia é a mesma coisa. https://dicionario.priberam.org/inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o#google_vignette Pode clicar em qualquer un dos portugueses. É a mesma coisa.